# Where is the Data Import Wizard Error Log

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am using Salesforce Professional Edition.  I am trying to locate the data import wizard log file.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I have import errors and want to see what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from one of the [documentations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=importing_person_accounts.htm&type=5) on Data Import Wizard:

> When we finish importing your data, we notify you by email. Review the results and resolve any errors that occurred.

You should check your email to see those results/errors. It will contain link to the result file.

Additionally you can access this file from navigating to `Setup --> Bulk Data Load Jobs` to view and download the results which will consist of success/errors

Comment: Thank you.  The errors came to me via email.  I don't seem to have the Bulk Data Load Jobs option.