# It is possible to show custom error message in import wizard?

Tags: trigger, data-import-wizard

I need to show custom error message when user imports data. If criteria is true then I would like to see error message in user interface and get file with errors. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no possibility to display the failure message on UI of data import wizard. The Import Wizard only provides statistics after finishing import.

As mentioned in the [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258476/where-is-the-data-import-wizard-error-log) you should check your email to see those results/errors. It will contain a link to the result file. Additionally, you can access this file from navigating to Setup --> Bulk Data Load Jobs to view and download the results which will consist of success/errors

Related article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323629&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

In regards to showing a custom error message, you can set up validation rules and the error results would show in the email received as attachment.See below image

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)